# Opencart .htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I'm having similar problem My url is like name.domain.com/subdoamin/store/index.php?...

and my htaccess file is :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.tpl">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

#<FilesMatch "\.ini">
 #Order deny,allow
 #Deny from all
#</files>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /store/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L,QSA]
```

however it is giving a `404 Not found` error

Comment: Similar problem to what?

Answer (score 2):

If your store folder is inside the *subdomain* folder your **RewriteBase** should be **/subdomain/store/**

Answer (score 1):

My subdomain resides under root/main site/test site.
Under admin->system->setting, you need to provide correct url path.
then under *.htaccess* file this modification worked for me,

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?*route*=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/testSite/.*$

Answer (score 0):

I dug into this and found you have to replace `_route_` with `route`.  This will resolve the issue.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
--> RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]`
```

but RewriteBase of subdomain or folder is required.

Comment: Thats not actually correct. `_route_` is required for rewritten urls to then be decoded