# OpenCart sub-domain .htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, opencart

I have installed opencart on my company's subdomain like so: http://store.example.in, that is, by creating a sub-domain below the main domain since I did not want to disturb the main site. Unfortunately I am unable to get clean SEO-friendly urls even after enabling them through the admin panel (System | Settings | Server | Use SEO URLs -> Yes). I also added the `.htaccess` file to the installation root, the partial contents of which are as below:

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried changing the `RewriteBase /` thingy to `RewriteBase /store.example.in/` and even
`RewriteBase /store/example.in/` but no-go there too.

I tried searching for an answer and found very few links to a solution which also included this: [Opencart .htaccess issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862691/opencart-htaccess-issue)
which also did not help much.

Comment: I am not familiar with OpenCart, but the sub-domain might be hosted at `/store`, so that's what you should have as *RewriteBase*.

Comment: Id depends on what your webhosting directory structure is. Usualy a subdirectory for subdomains lays next to the `www` directory and the URLs are set at the server accordingly. In this case You do not need to change anything. Even that `RewriteBase` should be set to `/`. What is Your webhosting root directory structure?

Comment: @faa, thank you for your reply. However AFAIK I would write /store if the store's root was the ``store`` sub-directory within the example.in domain. Anyway, I tried adding that to the .htacess too but still no success.

Comment: @shadyyx, I tried that too. Since I added the ``store`` sub-domain through the hosting provider's web panel and the cp automatically added the directory ``store.example.in`` within the ``public_html`` directory. I tried adding that too but still no headway there too.

Comment: You say `.htaccess file to the installation root`. What's the root directory for the installation, where the .htaccess file is located? It's simple. That's the directory you have to set as *RewriteBase* as there are several substitution URLs with relative paths.  Yo do need the RewriteBase unless the substitution URLs have absolute paths.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, I think I goofed up in the response above. It's not in the ``public_html`` directory. It's directly in the root directory like so: ``/store.example.in``. Incidentally, I also set up the company's wiki as a sub-domain and that's at ``/wiki.example.in``., while the company's main site is at ``example.in``.

Comment: @faa as an example, the contact us page is at:
http://store.example.in/index.php?route=information/contact
while the privacy policy is at:
http://store.example.in/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=3
(I'm sorry I am using example.in as the domain name but as a company policy I am not allowed to reveal the name of the store yet.)

Comment: Where is DocumentRoot pointing to? I guess to `public_html`, which is **root** in the web space. What's you primary domain, `example.in`? If so, there is a confusion. It seems clear to me that the sub-domains are `wiki` and `store`. Both hosted under `public_html` directory, in directories with the same name.

Comment: I think I may have found the problem. The .htaccess file was being read fine but then the seo keyword has to be manually added to each and every predefined page within the installation, like privacy policy and so forth. Within the admin panel, Catalog | Information will list all the pages within the default installation like contact us, privacy, etc. We have to edit each of these pages and within the Data tab add the ``SEO Keyword`` field which has to be unique site-wide. This SEO keyword then becomes the (SEO-friendly) url of the page. Thanks so much, @faa for your kind help! I'm grateful :)

Comment: I think I may have been barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Glad you found the problem. For future references, you might take into account what I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Sure faa! And I hope this comment stream helps others in the future.